# Mongodb/Mongoose fields and data still accessible after using $unset

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to remove a user if they have not verified their email after a certain time with mongoose. So I am setting a field called `verifyBy` to a date and giving it an expires time. then when the user verifies the email I am removing it with unset. This seems to be working. I can't see the field when looking in Mongodb Compass and the user doesn't expire so it seems to be unsetting the field.

The issue is I want to check if the user is verified before they login. So when I do this check I am still able to access the `verifyBy` field. Here is my user model:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  verifyBy: {
    type: Date,
    expires: '2m',
    default: Date.now,
  },
  register_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
})

const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)

export default User
```

Then in my verification route I am doing this to unset the field:

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id },
  { $unset: { verifyBy: 1 } }
)
```

This seems to work because in Compass you can see the `verifyBy` field is gone. Also the user is not removed now after the allotted time so at this point everything seems to be working.

[image: Mongodb Compass Image]

But then after all of this in my login route I want to check and see if the `verifyBy` field is still set before the user logs in and it is still set and accessible. Below in my login I do:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email: email })
console.log('verifyBy', user?.verifyBy)
```

And as you can see by the console log the `verifyBy` field is still there and accessible.

[image: Console log image]

I could just set another field called `verified` or something and just set that to true when the user verifies their email but I shouldn't have to if the `verifiedBy` field is not set. And what good does it do to unset something if it is still accessible by code. I feel like I am not doing something right but I'm not sure what.

Comment: In the example you show, do `_id`, `email`, and the Compass document all correspond to the same document?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Ya they are the same document. Verification is done by token with the _id as payload but obviously when the user logs in they wouldn't know their userID so they would do so by their email.

Comment: So, after 2 minutes, is the document removed because of the TTL index?

Comment: @rickhg12hs ya 2 minutes is just for testing but if the user doesn't verify their email by the 2 minutes then they are removed from the database.

Comment: I meant that specific document you show in the example where `console.log('verifyBy', user?.verifyBy)` displays a date.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes that is the User document that has the verifyBy field that is a Date and contains the expires field. I posted the schema a the top of the question. When the user signs up they are sent an email with a token that contains the user id. Then that token is used to verify their email. At that point I am trying to remove the `verifyBy` field which is a date that contains the expires value. All of that seems to work. But I want to check if the user's email is verified before they login and that `verifiyBy` Date is stlll accessible even though it is seemingly removed in Compass.

Comment: Is there any caching that might affect your app, but not Compass, etc.?  Do you have access to the MongoDB server logs where you can see collection access, etc.?

Comment: How does the value returned by `user?.verifyBy` compare to the current time when the login was attempted?

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunate behaviour happens because you are using a default value in your schema `default: Date.now,`. If you try to use `$unset` with another key in your schema that does not have a default value it will behave the way you expect.

I would suggest you simply set the date for the value of `verifyBy` whenever you pass in the values for `name`, `email` and `password` then you can remove the `default: Date.now,` property from your `verifyBy` key and it will behave the way you expect.